# Clusters become unavailable with ERROR status

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've created two GKE clusters with auto-upgrade feature. Suddenly lost all access to these clusters and see two REPAIR_CLUSTER operations for each one which are considered DONE (gcloud beta container operations list) and gcloud container clusters list shows me two my clusters with STAUS: ERROR.

P.S. As far as I know no one among our engineers have done no cluster-level operations during this period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a billing issue. I suppose as I have no access to a billing but an administrator in all rest, the error messages are as much obscure as possible.

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance, It is difficult to explain why the clusters return an ERROR status without looking at the log files, or the cluster. The issue here is at [the cluster master level](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture). The cluster master operates and runs the Kubernetes API server, core resource controllers, the scheduler, and somehow in your case, there seem to be errors in the master files. However, users do not have access to the GKE master, so it will difficult to investigate at your level.

Solutions:

1. Edit the cluster. This means that you could either create a new pod, node, daemonset, or deployment. The APIs will refresh the master, which could repair the errors in the cluster.
2. You could try to downgrade the cluster master (or node pool) to a previous version. If any issues were caused by the auto-upgrade feature, it will revert back to the original settings.
3. You could delete and recreate the cluster. This will refresh the master, but this would have to be done as a last resort, if all other options fail.
4. I also recommend that you create a new issue [in the Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/access-ui). A GKE support person will look at the issue, and will be able to inspect the cluster.